# Make user uploads go to different hard drive?

Tags: centos

I am using a pre-made social networking script where all user uploads go to site.com/public/user/

How can I make /public/user/ my secondary hard drive so all user uploads are uploaded to my second harddrive and not the primary hard drive. I have over 100GB of images, and I want them on my other HDD now. Thank you.

I am running CentOS 5.5 64bit w/ Apache and PHP

I have two 250GB Sata HDDs

```
#sudo parted /dev/sda print

Model: ATA WDC WD2500KS-00M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  107MB   107MB   primary   ext3         boot 
 2      107MB   8595MB  8488MB  primary   linux-swap        
 3      8595MB  10.7GB  2147MB  primary   ext3              
 4      10.7GB  250GB   239GB   extended                    
 5      10.7GB  250GB   239GB   logical   ext3              

Information: Don't forget to update /etc/fstab, if necessary.    
5 10.7GB 250GB 239GB logical ext3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure would look something like this.  You haven't provided much in the way of detail in your question, so I can't give you exact details.

- If the other drive is new, or never been used, then you need to set it up.  Create the partition and filesystem, then mount it somewhere.
- Create a folder on your other drive /otherdrive_mnt/site.com/public/user/
- Copy or move content from current location to the created folder
- Link the folder to the new drive by

  - Creating a symlink from site.com/public/user/ to /otherdrive_mnt/site.com/public/user/
  - Use a bind mount from site.com/public/user/ to /otherdrive_mnt/site.com/public/user/

Comment: You don't need a symlink: just mount to a temporary directory to copy the files, then (after making sure that /public/user is completely empty) mount it to /public/user. And don't forget to update your fstab so it gets automatically mounted when you boot.

Comment: Thank you! I am transferring to a new server, so I can just transfer all 100GB of images to the new server/secondary HDD. I am assuming my second HDD is " 4      10.7GB  250GB   239GB   extended" is extended mean it's already partitioned, or do I still need to partition it?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this would be to

- Find out where site.com/public/user
  lives within the filesystem.
- Partition and newfs the second drive
  as required
- Temporarily mount the second drive
  somewhere and copy the existing files
  to it.
- Disable uploads temporarily
- Unmount the second drive and mount it
  into the filesystem as noted above
- Enable uploads
- Make a suitable entry in /etc/fstab